# How to load a huge image into a database without Java Virtual Machine throwing OutOfMemory Error?

Tags: java, memory, out-of-memory, h2, bufferedimage

### Problem Statement

I need to load a float image of 10k rows and 3k cols and display it on a JPanel using `BufferedImage`. If I load the entire image using `FileChannel`, I get JVM OutOfMemory Error. I cannot hardcode the JVM to start with a larger memory size as it'll not solve the problem of opening the image on smaller machines.

I'm trying to load the image and divide it into tiles and store it in an in-memory database like H2 from which I'll access the appropriate tile and display it.

### Issues

To open and divide the image into a tile, I'd either have to open the entire image which defeats the problem or read each pixel/float (FileInputStream) which is excruciatingly slow.

(FileInputStream is slower than FileChannel)

I can read a band (all columns but less number of rows) using `FileChannel` and crop it to create a tile but this again is an issue as reading a band depends on number of columns I have which is again a problem, it the number of columns is very high, the JVM will throw OutOfMemoryError.

### Objective

Tile: A subset of image which can be handled by JVM.

Read an image tile by tile and store it in the In-Memory database. If and when I require the tiles, I'll fetch it from the In Memory database and show it on JPanel using `BufferedImage` class.

Comment: Hint: in-memory database stores the image in memory. There's no other way to cut it, if full image doesn't fit into app memory and causes OOM, all the tiles of that image will cause OOM too.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov true, the OP is probably meaning an embedded database. H2 can operate file based too.

Comment: JVM allocates less memory than that is provided by the RAM. So, In-memory database uses separate instance of JVM which it handles in its own way and generally doesn't get any OutOfMemoryError. I'm not low on memory itself rather low of memory allocated by the JVM. Like I said, I can't hard code more memory using -Xmx or -Xms as it'll result in my software occupying a lot of RAM in low end systems. @M. Prokhorov

Comment: @Joop Eggen Embedded database is what I mean. But, In memory would be better. Like I said, I'm not short of memory in some high end systems but the memory JVM allocates to the program which is way less than the free space in the RAM.